# Issues with MikTeX Distribution Download: Error Encountered during Installation

Tags: miktex, installing

I ran the setup-5.6.1+3f4a6a7-x64.exe (MikTeX Net Installer) on my PC (Windows 10 Pro) in an attempt to download the complete MikTeX distribution (Version: 14-Oct-2023) from the source depicted in the first image, highlighted in blue. Unfortunately, an error message occurs, as seen in the second image. Upon reviewing the logfile, I observed the following traces:

```
downloading https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/autosp.tar.lzma (expecting 271445 bytes)...

An error occurred:
  source file: 
  source line: 0
  message: Requested resource not found.
  info: url="https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/autosp.tar.lzma"
```

**first image:**
[image: first image]

**second image:**
[image: second image]

**Notification:**
I've identified that the link mentioned in the error message (https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/autosp.tar.lzma) is generating a `404 Not Found` error.
[image]

**Question:**
What steps can I take to resolve this issue and successfully download my complete MikTeX distribution?

---

**Action History:**

- 18-Oct-2023: I've opened a new issue on the MiKTeX repository. You can find it here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1391#issue-1950700735

Comment: That file isn't listed here: https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ ... so it can't find it ...

Comment: May be you can address it or open a ticket here; https://github.com/MiKTeX ?

Comment: @MS-SPO: I appreciate your response. However, I'm curious about why MikTex is attempting to download the file `autosp.tar.lzma`.

Comment: Fine. Good question to Miktex or whoever is involved.

Comment: @MS-SPO: I've opened a new issue on the MiKTeX repository. You can find it here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1391#issue-1950700735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue independently. I had been awaiting the release of the MikTeX distribution (Version: 26-Oct-2023). Fortunately, there are no issues with this particular version, and I have successfully downloaded the complete MikTeX distribution (Version: 26-Oct-2023) from the source indicated in the image below, highlighted in blue.

[image]

[image]